# Do there exist $a_k$ and $b_k$ so the equation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (a_k \sin(kx) + b_k \cos(kx)) = 0$ has no roots?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, roots

Do there exist real numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, ..., b_n$ such that the equation
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (a_k \sin(kx) + b_k \cos(kx)) = 0$$
has no solutions?

Comment: Using complex numbers $c_k=a_k+ib_k$, $z=\cos x+i\sin x$, the question is whether $f(z)=\sum c_kz^k$ intersects the real axis for some $z$ on the unit circle.

Comment: The integral of this trigonometric polynomial over any interval of length $2\pi$ is zero. Since this function is continuous and real-valued, it must possess a zero within that interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as sos440 says:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \left[ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (a_k \sin(kx) + b_k \cos(kx)) \right]
\; dx = 0
$$
A strictly positive or strictly negative function cannot integrate to zero.  Thus
$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (a_k \sin(kx) + b_k \cos(kx))$ is neither.  So
there exist real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $f(a) > 0$, $f(b) < 0$.  By intermediate value theorem, $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$.

Comment: thanks @Goos and @sos440!!!