# Finite linear combination of sines and cosines has a zero (without integration)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Consider the following linear combination with real parameters. $$\sum _{k=1}^n a_k \cos(\lambda_k t)+ b_k \sin(\lambda_k t)$$

How can I prove such a combination always has a zero? I know that a sufficiently large derivative has a zero, but I am not sure how to deduce anything about the original sum itself. I would prefer a solution avoiding integration.

Comment: "a sufficiently large derivative has a zero": what do you mean ?

Comment: Suppose $\lambda _1 < \cdots <\lambda n$. Then for large $N$ the derivative $f^{(N)}$ is dominated by $a_n\cos \lambda_n t+b_n \sin \lambda_n t$, which take positive and negative value. By the intermediate value theorem, $f^{(N)}$ therefore has a zero.

Comment: I know you want to avoid it, but for reference,  here's a solution that uses integration https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792770/do-there-exist-a-k-and-b-k-so-the-equation-sum-limits-k-1n-a-k-sin

Comment: @StefanLafon the $\lambda _i$ are not integers, so I don't think that solution carries.

Comment: Ahh good point. Sorry. Although, wouldn't that work for $\lambda_i$ being rational numbers, and then for the general case, you'd just have to approximate $\lambda_i$ with rationals? Then the two sums (original and approximate) would be very close.

Comment: @StefanLafon that is a nice idea. I will wait to see if anyone gives a neat answer before trying to write it out.

Comment: If you can find a value $t$ for which all the cosine terms are $0$, if the sine terms are not also $0$, then the value for $-t$ will be the opposite as for $t$. So somewhere between it must cross $0$. If the $\lambda_i$ are all rational, such a $t$ can be found. For irrational $t$, again a good approximation by rationals should give a $t$ for which the difference from $0$ is much smaller than for the sine terms, still allowing you to prove the function values at $t$ and $-t$ are of opposite sign.